# I want my classes to provide meta data in an uniform way. How?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a bunch of classes in our data access layer who speak with database tables (part of ORM solution). Now, I want for my classes to provide some data about that for automation and documentation purposes. Something like - Table name, Primary key name, Description column, etc... Of course, valuable information is just to differentiate data access classes from the rest of them.

Not sure how to implement this. If I go with static properties then I'm forced to use reflection and it's difficult to check whether class has information or not and there is an issue that programmer might include some information but not all which would break things.

If I go with interfaces then I need to create object from class to extract data and classes have no uniform constructor to do that. Interface has no way to define a necessary constructor.

Tips?

Comment: What about writing comments in a special way (eg. to be read by doxygen)? You can read all your source files searching that special comments and collect the informations you need. No extra members, no extra interfaces in your classes, just an easy parser to write. That comment is already self documenting in your source code.

Comment: Of course - custom attributes. Completely forgot.